# My Dolphin isn't Noticing Newly Created Files

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, kde, dolphin

In the past, the Dolphin file manager maintained awareness of newly created files. For example, if I saved a new file to a folder that I also had opened with Dolphin, Dolphin would immediately show that newly saved file almost instantly.

For the past few weeks however, I'm constantly having to hit F5 (in Dolphin) to see files that are really there but Dolphin doesn't know it yet.

I don't know if this is bug, or some setting I've accidentally changed, but I sure would appreciate some direction on how to fix it.

Comment: Are the files on a network share?

Comment: @OrganicMarble No sir: They're on the same SSD as the OS.

Comment: Since I received no suggestions here, I submit a bug to both [Kubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dolphin/+bug/1890791) and [KDE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=425098).

Comment: I recently shifted from Nautilus, i thought this is how it worked! XD